# getArrayLength() is returning a huge number...

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am trying to understand jni, so I started hacking up hellojni, and I ran into this problem.

My java code looks like this:

```
                    short[] buf = new short[16];
                    Log.d("hello", "before!");
                    write(buf, 0, 16);
```

and my C code looks like this:

```
jint
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_write(JNIEnv* env, jshortArray buf, jint off, jint len)
{
    char debug[1024];
    int ii = 0;
    jsize cbuflen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, buf);

    sprintf(debug, "array length: %d", cbuflen);
    LOGD(debug);
...
...
```

The output is:

array length: 1079082088

Why is the array length so big?

Comment: this is weird, even passing a simple integer doesn't work!  what's going on here!!!

Comment: Is this really your entire function, or is there anything missing?

Answer (score 4):

Could you show your entire JNI file? You are not declaring the target object in your JNI function. Usually the arguments are JNIEnv* env, jobject javaObject, etc. This means that what you believe is the jshortArray is actually the pointer to a Java object, which would explain the weird results you are getting.

Comment: May as well spell it out: Your function should look like this: `jint
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_write(JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObj, jshortArray buf, jint off, jint len)`.